# How to express an img src using the mvc 6 syntax?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following in my view:

```
<img src="/Home/UserImageByOffice365Name?office365Name=@Uri.EscapeUriString(User.Identity.Name)" />
```

In the past I would have used `Url.Action` or something similar to create the link for the `src` attribute.  How would accomplish the same thing with the `asp-*` (e.g. `asp-controller`, etc...) set of attribute functionality (e.g. asp.net mvc 6)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today, There is no specific tag helper syntax for rendering the image source tag from something like asp-src-controller and asp-src-action etc..) in MVC 6

The best thing you can do is to use the existing Html  helper method `Url.Action` helper method so that it will take care of escaping space and other trouble characters.

```
<img src="@Url.Action("UserImageByOffice365Name","Home",
                                          new {office365Name="some name with space"})" />
```